# TypeMock Isolator and TFS2010 team build

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, typemock

Can anyone point me at a decent walkthrough regarding getting Typemock 6.2 to play nice with TFS workflow? I've tried to follow the Release Note.doc document, but it just doesn't sense. Note I'm pretty new to workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Copy TypeMock.TFS2010.dll from Typemock installation folder 
to `..\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE`.
After doing this you will be able to edit a template.

Comment: I have no problem editing the template and adding the activities.